# Unable to login after placing hadoop.sh in /etc/profile.d folder

Tags: login-screen

I am stuck and can't login... When I get into the ubuntu login screen and enter my password, it takes me back to the same screen. 
I was able to install ubuntu and run it for a few days. I was trying to install Apache hive but received some errors. The issue started when I modified my /etc/profile.d folder by placing a hadoop.sh file in it based on the inputs below 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688466/cannot-find-hadoop-installation-hadoop-home-must-be-set-or-hadoop-must-be-in-t

After I restarted my m/c, I have not been able to login. I am now unable to remove the hadoop.sh file from root and tty1 as it says 'read only filesystem'. Please help.

Comment: Guys ...i was able to resolve the issue by going to root and then issuing sudo rm

Answer (score 0):

OP wrote:

> I was able to resolve the issue by going to root and then issuing `sudo rm`.